# how to call symfony command in a FTP server?

Tags: php, ftp, symfony4

my production server is only accessible via FTP. I need to change the logo of my team but it require to clear the cache.

In general I would like to know how to run a a php console command via a `index.php` file ?
It would allow me to continue using some commands suche as :

```
$ php bin/console cache:clear
```

Comment: Clearing cache from a route is a very bad way but i understand your problem. In your action controller, call container service and with it you can run symfony command: https://symfony.com/doc/current/console/command_in_controller.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually "clear" the cache by deleting the content of `/var/cache/prod`

It won't warm up the cache, so, the first browse of any page will re create it